# Swift Cannot find "" in Scope, from local Package

Tags: swift, xcode, package

I'm new to packages with swift and I was trying to create a simple function that will authorize the user but Xcode can't seem to find my "ApiCalls" struct even tho I have set everything to public and I followed a tutorial on how to make a package. I keep getting this error

[image]

This is my package

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I tried looking this up and the main issue was that my structs and variables were not set to public. But even changing that Xcode does not seem to find it.

Update: I made the it static and I still get the same error message:

```
public struct ApiCalls {
public init(currentAPIDomain: String = "my.url") {
    ApiCalls.currentAPIDomain = currentAPIDomain
}

public static var currentAPIDomain : String = "https://castle-learning-1541513232785.appspot.com/"

public static func RestApiRequest<T:Decodable>(method:ApiCallsRequestMethods, endpoint: String, model: T.Type, requirements: ApiCallsRequestRequirements) async throws -> T {
    
    guard var endpointURL = URL(string: currentAPIDomain + endpoint) else { throw ApiCallErrors.DomainMalformed }
    
    if requirements.subtitles != nil && requirements.subtitles == true {
        endpointURL = URL(string: endpoint)!
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: endpointURL)
    
    switch method {
    case .GET:
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
    case .POST:
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
    case .PUT:
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
    case .DELETE:
        request.httpMethod = "DELETE"
    }
    
    if requirements.subtitles != nil && requirements.subtitles == true {
        request.addValue("fdD7F8Orql9WBolf9BgjrYIDFcFhH9Hz", forHTTPHeaderField: "Api-Key")
    }
    
    if Array(requirements.token.keys)[0] == true {
        request.addValue("Bearer \(requirements.token[true]!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    }
    
    if Array(requirements.body.keys)[0] == true {
        let body: [String:Any] = requirements.body[true]!
        let finalBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)
        request.httpBody = finalBody
    }
    
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    guard let (data, response) = try? await URLSession.shared.data(for: request) else {
        throw ApiCallErrors.InvalidData
    }
    guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { throw ApiCallErrors.Unexpected }
    
    guard let decodedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) else {
        throw ApiCallErrors.ErrorDecoding
    }
    
    return decodedData
}

public static func login(username: String, password: String) async throws -> String {
    do {
        let results = try await RestApiRequest(method: .GET, endpoint: "ptv/login", model: Login_SignUp_Model.self, requirements: ApiCallsRequestRequirements(token: [false : ""], body: [true : ["email" : username, "password":password]]))
        return results.message
    } catch {
        throw error
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `login(…)` is not declared as a static function but that is how you call it. And always post code as text and not as images.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Still get the same error. I have posted the code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with your methods being static, but access control is important. Your Swift package is considered a separate module, therefore anything below public is inaccessible from elsewhere ( eg. your app ).

Your original `APICalls` code is fine. It's hard to tell from the screenshots, but here are three things to try:

1. It appears that you have two projects in the same workspace. Your package is referenced inside the `pixelstv` project, so you won't be able to access it from the `Pods` project.
2. Something could be wrong in your `Package.swift` file. It should follow this basic structure:

```
// swift-tools-version: 5.7

//
//  APIName: Configuration
//  Developed by _
//

//  MARK: - Imports

import PackageDescription

//
//

//  MARK: - Variables

let package = Package (
    
    name: "APIName",
    
    products: [
        
        .library (
            
            name: "APIName",
            targets: [ "TargetName" ]
            
        ),
        
    ],
    
    dependencies: [ ],
    
    targets: [
        
        .target (
            
            name: "APIName",
            dependencies: [ ],
            path: "sources"
            
        ),
        
        .testTarget (
            
            name: "APINameTests",
            dependencies: [ "APIName" ],
            path: "tests"
            
        ),
        
    ]
    
)

//
//
```

3. It could be an Xcode quirk — hasn't recognized the updated access control, lost the ability to type check completely, etc. Try cleaning the build folder, rebuilding, restarting, resetting the package caches, and even removing + re-adding the package to the project.

Xcode seems quite reliable using package dependancies ( from GitHub ) but using local packages introduces a lot of bugs. Some I've noticed only days into using local packages are builds cancelling mysteriously 25% of the time, and Xcode crashing presumably due to a package loading loop when trying to use previews. You can also only reference the local package in one open project or window at a time, otherwise you won't be able to edit or access the package.

If you're really having issues, it might be a good idea to consider developing your APIs inside your project, then moving them to a package once they're complete and pushing them to GitHub.

In response to @JoakimDanielson comment: I agree in most cases, but the screenshots of Xcode may have revealed the problem here.